# VBA code window - buttons disappeared from menu

Tags: remote-access

I am using the code window in VBA (what is the technical term for this?  Session window?).

The "play sign" button for "continue", and all the other buttons have all disappeared. Only the grey background is visible.  If I hover the cursor over the slot where the symbol should be, the description appears, and the buttons work if I press them.  However, the symbols have disappeared.

First noticed this last night and assumed it was a temporary bug (I am using Citrix).  However, still happening this morning.

Does anyone know what might cause this and how to fix?

Comment: Can you confirm if this is only occuring via a remote session ? And double check the settings of your session. I'm not sure if this is a VBa issue or a remote session/graphics issue

Comment: Yes - it is.  And yes, I agree that it might be a remote session issue

Comment: I would guess that your machine or the target machine's graphic drivers have been updated, or that your settings have changed. Make sure your graphic settings for the session are set correctly